# Why is Plotly displaying empty space when displaying a graph through django data?

Tags: javascript, django, plotly

I am trying to print a pie graph using from Django but it is showing an empty space instead of printing the pie chart. I used the instructions from https://plotly.com/javascript/pie-charts/ but I am getting an error.  How do I fix it?

views.py

```
labels = list(account_graph.keys()) # ['Food', 'Gas', 'Friends'] 
data = list(account_graph.values()) # [-6.09, -20.0, -7.0]

return render(request, "finances/account.html", {'labels': labels, 'data': data})
```

account.html

```
<div id='expenses'></div>

<script>

      var data = [{
        values: {{data|safe}},
        labels: {{labels|safe}},
        type: 'pie'
      }];

      var layout = {
        height: 400, 
        width: 500
      }

      Plotly.newPlot('expenses', data, layout);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your values are all negative.

Non numeric or negative values are ignored in the pie chart sector calculations ([source code](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/dc3c342f346bd6effad210414f377345fe3e2d47/src/traces/pie/calc.js#L42)), so no slices show up making the graph look empty.